# How to create a book oriented script?

Tags: php

We were supposed to create an object oriented script that contains a book and page class as our homework. Now I've been trying it all week and got nowhere. (I'm new to php this was my second lesson in the class)

I created the mentioned classes, then made an array of page numbers to echo them out between 1-10.

```
class Bookpages
{
    public function pages()
    {
        $pages = array [
            '1,',
            '2'
            '3'
            '4'
            '5'
            '6'
            '7'
            '8'
            '9'
            '10'


            ,
        ];
        foreach ($pages as $page)
            echo $page;
    }
```

It wasn't going anywhere and I had no idea what to do next, any pointers would be appreciated, really want to learn from this.

Comment: Please show your research effort before posting StackOverflow questions. We all make mistakes, but I don't see a week worth's effort here as it seems to me that you haven't even corrected the syntax which is easy to detect on your PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, right now your code example does not contain any "Page" Class nor a "Book" class.

In general, a class is defined with the keyword `class`, so you need something like

```php
class Book {
    // ...
}
```

Your representation of pages is not object-oriented, but just an Array.

Take a look into [PHP Object-oriented programming](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/oop-intro) first to understand the basics here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are missing comma after each array value. Secondly, return the array and print it in the view page (where you want to display the count). Something like this:

```
class Page {   
    public function pages() {   
        return $pages = [   
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            '10'
        ];  
    }   
}
```

and then on pages (view) page, use foreach loop to print array values, like this

```
require 'Page.php'; 

$pageClass = new Page();
$pages = $pageClass->pages();      

foreach($pages as $page) {    
    echo $page . '<br>';    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying this now, did this: made another php file called "page.view.php" and then insert the second section of your code. Also replaced my original code in page.php with yours and then saved the files. Now when i open page.php it's blank (i know that's good) and page.view.php gives: pages(); foreach($pages as $page) { echo $page; } - Did i do something wrong there? Sorry I'm still very very new to this :p

Comment: Don't open pages.php on the server. Try opening page.view.php. Also make sure that error_reporting and display_errors are turned on in php.ini file.

Comment: Okay i'll turn it off. Right now it's displaying this: https://imgur.com/a/OnFUm0d on page.view

Comment: btw i added random letters in there to see if it would still display it, pls ignore that part

Comment: I think you are not calling Pages class properly in page.view.php. Also, make sure both Page.php and page.view.php are in some directory.

Comment: Please study about object oriented programming before proceeding [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm)